# Logitech headset USB not working properly on Kubuntu 14.04

Tags: kubuntu, pulseaudio

I have a Logitech USB Headset. It worked fine on Kubuntu 13.04, 64 bits, but not on Kubuntu 14.04, 64 bits.

When I plug in the headset, Kmix does not show it on the master channel window (Right click on Kmix icon at system tray --- Select Master Channel...). But, when I restart the computer, with the headset plugged in, then, it appears in the Kmix Master channel window.

On Kubuntu 13.04, it appears when I plug it at any moment, no restart is required.

The following appear when I open KSystemLog and plug the USB Headset:

```
05/16/14 10:52:23 PM    GTRONICK    kernel  [10074.604429] usb 2-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 12 using ehci-pci
05/16/14 10:52:24 PM    GTRONICK    kernel  [10074.703476] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=0a0b
05/16/14 10:52:24 PM    GTRONICK    kernel  [10074.703488] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
05/16/14 10:52:24 PM    GTRONICK    kernel  [10074.703495] usb 2-1.2: Product: Logitech USB Headset
05/16/14 10:52:24 PM    GTRONICK    kernel  [10074.703500] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Logitech
05/16/14 10:52:24 PM    GTRONICK    kernel  [10074.735240] input: Logitech Logitech USB Headset as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.3/input/input24
05/16/14 10:52:24 PM    GTRONICK    kernel  [10074.735545] hid-generic
0003:046D:0A0B.0008: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.00 Device [Logitech Logitech USB Headset] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2/input3
05/16/14 10:52:24 PM    GTRONICK    mtp-probe   checking bus 2, device 12: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2"
05/16/14 10:52:24 PM    GTRONICK    mtp-probe   bus: 2, device: 12 was not an MTP device
05/16/14 10:52:24 PM    GTRONICK    rtkit-daemon[1843]  Successfully made thread 4108 of process 2129 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
05/16/14 10:52:24 PM    GTRONICK    rtkit-daemon[1843]  Supervising 7 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
```

Then, I open the KMix master channel window, but the Headset is not shown

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UPDATE 28/05/14 (DD/MM/YY) LAST UPDATE]---------------------------------------

Recently, I have found another solution. This consist on:

If USB Headset is not recognized:

1. Unplug it
2. Right click on KMIX tray icon
3. Select master channel
4. On the KMIX window, click on cancel button
5. Plug your Headset in
6. Right click on KMIX tray icon
7. The USB Headset now must be shown

[UPDATES]----------------------------------------------------------------------------

After computer reboot with the Headset plugged in, the headset work fine. I have removed it from PC, then replug it, and work again, KMix show it. Now it detects it at any moment!. Is something strange.

---

HAHA! I have detected something strange, if I reboot the computer without the Headset plugged in, Kmix show it when I plug it in. But, if I have the headset plugged in, and go to the KMix icon, and select master channel, and then, select the default laptop sound hardware, then, if I unplug the Headset ant replug it, it is NOT shown on KMix master channel window. And here is the solution!:

If Headset is not detected on Kmix Master channel window, do the Following:

first unplug the Headset, if it was plugged in before...

1. Right click on KMix icon on system tray.
2. Click on "Select Master Channel..."
3. Clik on the round check button, left to the name of the default listed Hardware (Make sure you click on the round button! it must be filled)
4. Close the Master Channel window
5. Plug the Headset in.
6. Go to KMix master channel chooser again
7. Now, the Headset must be shown

I suppose that is a software issue, related to KMix, but I am not sure.